# $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1$ has three real roots, find the minimum of $f(2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+1$ has three real roots, 
find the minimum of $f(2)$.

Since $f(x)$ has three real roots, 
the discriminant of $f(x)$ is not less than $0$, 
that is, 
$$\Delta=a^2b^2-4b^3-4a^3-27+18ab\geq 0.$$

I don't know how to use this inequality to find the minimum of 
$f(2)=4a+2b+9$.

Comment: Did you mean to write "is greater than $0$" or to write the inequality as $\Delta=a^2b^2-4b^3-4a^3-27+18ab\leq 0.$?

Comment: oh~thank you for point out the mistakes.

Comment: My first thought is to consider the boundary case of $\Delta=0$, and see what constraints that imposes on $f(2)$.

Comment: I don't understand. How can the answer be independent of $a$ and $b$? Make a cubic poly with $n$,$\frac1{n}$ and $-1$ as roots so that it satisfies the constraints in the problem. $f(2)$ can be made arbitrarily negative by choosing larger $n$, right?

Comment: For another example of $f(2)$'s lack of a lower bound: With $a=b<-1$, $\Delta$ is positive but $f(2)=6a+9$ can be made arbitrarily negative. (Interestingly, there does appear to be a lower bound for $f(2)$ if it's one real root and two complex.)

Comment: are you sure to find min? a<0,b<0 and large enough, $\Delta >0$ is always true. which means $f(2)$ don't have min., But $f(2)$ do have max.

Comment: @Semidassical http://goo.gl/QggzfT

Comment: Thanks everyone for give me a countexample to point out the mistake of the question.